# Will there be any issue if I change default subnet to 2.2.2.0 and 3.3.3.0 for NAT and Host only in my Virtual Network Editor of VMWare Workstation?

Tags: networking, router, vmware, vmware-workstation

I amy trying to learn VMWare Workstation and for making the IP address remember easily I want to change them

- For `NAT`       (subnet mask 255.255.255.0) I want to change
  192.168.163.0 To **2.2.2.0** and
- For `Host Only` (subnet mask 255.255.255.0) I want to change 192.168.240.0 To **3.3.3.0**

My Home Router IP address is 192.168.1.1

I want to do some practicals on Active Directory, FTP, VPN, Load balancing etc using VMWare Workstation Pro. I want to know if this configuration setting will create some communication issuess for some labs during testing?

After my changes The configuration looks like below

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can do this with a custom network.  I just did this for VMnet2 and it appeared to work.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that @John

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it could cause a problem, but only for you. If you wanted to browse to a site that is hosted in (real) *2.2.2.0/24* or *3.3.3.0/24*, this would not be possible. *2.2.2.0/24* is owned by Orange, a French ISP/telecom company. *3.3.3.0/24* is owned by Amazon and used for their AWS offering, specifically for EC2 virtual machines.

To minimize conflict potential in this regard, use smaller networks. This would of course mean you couldn’t run as many VMs concurrently with these networks.